# How to avoid URL encoding in ADF?

Tags: internet-explorer, oracle-adf

We get some URLs from a data provider. The URLs are displayed properly in the XML files and are also imported correctly to a WCC server. We are using Oracle ADF as the framework.

Now to the issue:

E.g. the URL by the provider is "www.somelink.com/query=%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC`&amp;`test=1234"

But the application renders it as: "www.somelink.com/query=äöü&test=1234"

Of course nearly every browser supports UTF-8 by default (especially in query strings) but not IE11... I know you can enable UTF-8 query support in IE11 but not an option for this issue. Also IE11 is the "main browser" in the company (government agency). It's not possible to manipulate the URLs directly.

Is there a way to fix this issue in ADF?

Comment: You can try to decode the url in your program then send it to browser, you can check [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/10752742#10752742) in oracle community. Also find [another post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2453925) and you could check it for more information.

Comment: Sadly none of these two are an option without changing the whole process of rendering/parsing the data. The URLs are parsed together with some other (non URL) content so I don't have any direct access to the URLs.

Comment: As I don't have Oracle ADF environment and don't know the detail about your application, I would like to ask: Are the urls percent-encoded manually or the ADF framework encodes the urls to utf-8 automatically? IF it's the former, I think you could ask the data provider don't percent-encode the urls, just use [IRIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) . If it's the latter, I think it's a issue of ADF and you could consult [Oracle Support Community](https://www.oracle.com/communities/) to solve the problem.

Comment: You can try to disable URL rewriting for session tracking in weblogic-application.xml > Session

Comment: @YuZhou It seems like we had a method which translated percent-encoded URLs to their specific letters and we removed it but sadly it didn't fix the issue entirely and caused a new issue. We changed the method so only the domain is getting the translated letter.

Comment: @Cedric Thank you for the hint. We'll check this out if it works works!